# get columns contain specific string

Tags: python, awk, text-processing

I have a file that like follows:

```
cat text.txt
a1       a2       j
h       a1
k       p       a1       a2      a3
```

And I want to get the columns than all match with a string "a".

```
a1    a2
a1
a1    a2    a3
```

I'm try used awk, but only get the last, not all.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^a/){arr=$i}} print arr}' text.txt
a2
a1
a3
```

Comment: Do you have something you've tried you need help with?

Comment: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^a/){arr=$i}} print arr}' text.txt`
But only get the last, not all.

Comment: You should put that in your question.

Comment: @hope: you missed appending matched field to variable `arr`, [see corrected code below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743707/get-columns-contain-specific-string/42744799#42744799)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to `get columns contain specific string` is:

```
$ awk '{
    c=0
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ( index($i,"a") ) {
            printf "%s%s", (c++ ? OFS : ""), $i
        }
    }
    if (c) {
        print ""
    }
}' file
a1 a2
a1
a1 a2 a3
```

That will work for any string "a" appearing in any position of any field, will not produce false matches when the target string contains regexp metacharacters, and will not print a blank line when there are not matches.

Answer (score 2):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

**Input**

```
$ cat file
a1       a2       j
h       a1
k       p       a1       a2      a3
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '{s="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^a/)s=(s?s OFS:"") $i; if(s)print s}' file
a1 a2
a1
a1 a2 a3
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '{                                        # call awk
        s="";                                 # set var s with null value, in fact it reset variable s for each line/record/row read by awk 
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                    # NF gives no of fields in record, so loop through first to last field of current record/line/row
                if($i~/^a/)s=(s?s OFS:"") $i; # if current field($i) starts with a then, if variable s has something before then concatenate s with output separator and current field value, else set s with current field


        if(s)                                 # if s has something then  
            print s                           # print s
      }
     ' file
```

Read more about [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#AWK)

```
s = ( s ? s OFS : "" ) $i;

      ^
  Above one is same as below

# Or if(s != "") or if(length(s))
if(s)
{
    s = s OFS $i
}else
{
    s = $i
}
```

Comment: Nice. Better if have a detailed explanation.

Comment: Best wish for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) from Python doc.And have a try.Open the file,and  use `for` loop to get content of each line as a string.

Then [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string and [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) the list to get the fields you want,if you want a string,use `join`.

```
with open("tryme.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        #split the string and filter it.
```

**Try to code yourself,if you're stuck then ask it.StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service.**

Comment: First, thanks for your suggestion. I have learning python total a week. So, your suggestion is more important for me. The follows is my try resulted and it also can achieve my purpose. Did you have any more suggestion.

`with open("xxxx_C.csv") as f:
    for line in f :
        print line
        a=line.split(";")
        print a
        b=filter(lambda k: 'GO:' in k, a)
        print b`

Answer (score 0):

@hope: try following too:

```
awk '{gsub(/[^a[0-9]]*/," ");gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"");print}'   Input_file
```

Explanation: globally substitute all things in line apart from fields which doesn't have a string in them. as you haven't mentioned about if there could be a mix fields(which may have a and something else too) so not considering that part, in case of mix values(of string a and others) it will only print a's.
Then substituting space starting from line and ending with space to NULL in line, then printing the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{j=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^a/){printf (++j<2?"":FS) $i};print""}' urfile
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: It will print newline char even if there is not a single field which starts with `a`

Comment: That doesn't print fields that contain a string `a`, it prints fields that start with a regexp `a`. The OPs sample input/output hides those distinctions. Also, never do `printf $i` unless you have a very specific purpose in mind and fully understand the risks. Always do `printf "%s", $i` instead. Imagine the difference when run against data some day where `$i` ends up containing printf formatting characters like `%s`.